# Couchbase / Python Access to sample project throws error UnAmbiguousTimeoutException error code 14

Tags: python, docker-compose, couchbase

I am trying to wrap my head arround couchbase DB. For that I am starting a couchbase cluster via docker-compose.

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  couchbase1:                        # Starts a first node with the name couchbase1.
    image: couchbase:enterprise     # defines the image that should be used the Tags enterprise and community can be used to define the version that should be used. Couchbase defaults to the enterprise version.
    ports:
    - "8091-8096:8091-8096"         # the port 8091 supports the webinterface acsses.
    - "11210-11211:11210-11211"
    volumes:
    - ./db-data1:/opt/couchbase/var  # Saves the folder "/opt/couchbase/var" in the folder "db-data" relative to this file"
  
  couchbase2:                       # Starts a second node with the name couchbase2.
    image: couchbase:enterprise
    ports:
    - "8090:8091"                   # A secondary webinterterface piped to 8090
    volumes:
    - ./db-data2:/opt/couchbase/var # A secondary memory for the second node in the test cluster

volumes:
  db-data1:
  db-data2:
```

I assume that I can fully access `couchbase1`. I configured both and connected them via port 8091 to have a cluster with multiple nodes.

I then tried to acces the cluster via `couchbase==4.1.1` with the code as shown in the example after loading the test data. The data exists and can be accesed over the webinterface.

After executing the example code as given in the documentation on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/couchbase/) as shown below I am recieving an error code 14

```py
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.auth import PasswordAuthenticator

# options for a cluster and SQL++ (N1QL) queries
from couchbase.options import ClusterOptions, QueryOptions
cluster = Cluster.connect('couchbase://localhost',                     
                          ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(
                              'Administrator',
                              'some-pw-that-is-better-than-this!'
                          )))

# get a reference to our bucket
bucket = cluster.bucket('travel-sample')

# get a reference to the default collection
cb_coll = bucket.default_collection()

# get a document
result = cb_coll.get('airline_10')
```

I am recieving the following error at the last line:

> UnAmbiguousTimeoutException: <ec=14, category=couchbase.common, message=unambiguous_timeout (14), context=KeyValueErrorContext:{'retry_attempts': 0, 'key': 'airline_10', 'bucket_name': 'travel-sample', 'scope_name': '_default', 'collection_name': '_default', 'opaque': 0, 'status_code': 0}, C Source=C:\Jenkins\workspace\python\sdk\python-scripted-build-pipeline\py-client\src\kv_ops.cxx:211>

This documentation is not realy helpfull to me: [docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/ref/error-codes.html#14-unambiguoustimeout)
If somebody has any Idear what is wrong, how do debug something like this or anything in that direction I would apreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Call wait_until_ready before calling get(). Without calling wait_until_ready first, the default 2.5 second timeout on get() might expire before the SDK is done creating the connetion.

https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client/couchbase_api/couchbase_core.html