# Connect to Couchbase Capella with Python: UnAmbiguousTimeoutException

Tags: python, couchbase

I am trying to connect to Couchbase Capella using the Python SDK. I have tried doing this exactly as outlined here,
https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/hello-world/start-using-sdk.html

This is what my code looks like,

```
from datetime import timedelta

# needed for any cluster connection
from couchbase.auth import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
# needed for options -- cluster, timeout, SQL++ (N1QL) query, etc.
from couchbase.options import (ClusterOptions, ClusterTimeoutOptions,
                               QueryOptions)


# Update this to your cluster
endpoint = "<cluster>.cloud.couchbase.com"
username = "<my-user>"
password = "<my-password>"
bucket_name = "travel-sample"
# User Input ends here.


# Connect options - authentication
auth = PasswordAuthenticator(username, password)

# get a reference to our cluster
options = ClusterOptions(auth)
# Sets a pre-configured profile called "wan_development" to help avoid latency issues
# when accessing Capella from a different Wide Area Network
# or Availability Zone(e.g. your laptop).
options.apply_profile('wan_development')
cluster = Cluster('couchbases://{}'.format(endpoint), options)
```

However, I keep getting the following error,

```
couchbase.exceptions.UnAmbiguousTimeoutException: UnAmbiguousTimeoutException(<ec=14, category=couchbase.common, message=unambiguous_timeout (14), C Source=/home/ec2-user/workspace/python/sdk/python-packaging-pipeline/py-client/src/connection.cxx:199>)
```

This does not help, because the exception is raised at the call to `connect()`,

[Couchbase / Python Access to sample project throws error UnAmbiguousTimeoutException error code 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934711/couchbase-python-access-to-sample-project-throws-error-unambiguoustimeoutexcep)

I saw a few other similar posts, but they have not helped.

Note that I have allowed my IP address as well.

What is going on here?

EDIT: Here are the DEBUG logs for my script,

```
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.362] [34212,34212] [debug] 1632ms, Selected nameserver: "127.0.0.53" from "/etc/resolv.conf"
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.416] [34212,34212] [debug] 54ms, open cluster, id: "db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516", core version: "1.0.0-dp.8", {"bootstrap_nodes":[{"hostname":"cb.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com","port":"11207"}],"options":{"analytics_timeout":"120000ms","bootstrap_timeout":"120000ms","config_idle_redial_timeout":"300000ms","config_poll_floor":"50ms","config_poll_interval":"2500ms","connect_timeout":"20000ms","disable_mozilla_ca_certificates":false,"dns_config":{"nameserver":"127.0.0.53","port":53,"timeout":"20000ms"},"dump_configuration":false,"enable_clustermap_notification":false,"enable_compression":true,"enable_dns_srv":true,"enable_metrics":true,"enable_mutation_tokens":true,"enable_tcp_keep_alive":true,"enable_tls":true,"enable_tracing":true,"enable_unordered_execution":true,"idle_http_connection_timeout":"4500ms","key_value_durable_timeout":"20000ms","key_value_timeout":"20000ms","management_timeout":"120000ms","max_http_connections":0,"metrics_options":{"emit_interval":"600000ms"},"network":"auto","query_timeout":"120000ms","resolve_timeout":"20000ms","search_timeout":"120000ms","show_queries":false,"tcp_keep_alive_interval":"60000ms","tls_verify":"peer","tracing_options":{"analytics_threshold":"1000ms","key_value_threshold":"500ms","management_threshold":"1000ms","orphaned_emit_interval":"10000ms","orphaned_sample_size":64,"query_threshold":"1000ms","search_threshold":"1000ms","threshold_emit_interval":"10000ms","threshold_sample_size":64,"view_threshold":"1000ms"},"transactions_options":{"cleanup_config":{"cleanup_client_attempts":false,"cleanup_lost_attempts":false,"cleanup_window":"0ms","collections":[]},"durability_level":"none","expiration_time":"0ns","query_config":{"scan_consistency":"not_bounded"}},"trust_certificate":"","use_ip_protocol":"any","user_agent_extra":"pycbc/4.1.8 (python/3.8.18)","view_timeout":"120000ms"}}
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.425] [34212,34214] [debug] 8ms, Query DNS-SRV: address="cb.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com", service="_couchbases", nameserver="127.0.0.53:53"
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.897] [34212,34214] [debug] 472ms, DNS UDP returned 1 records
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.897] [34212,34214] [info] 0ms, replace list of bootstrap nodes with addresses from DNS SRV of "cb.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com": ["svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207"]
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.898] [34212,34214] [debug] 0ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516]: use default CA for TLS verify
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.898] [34212,34214] [debug] 0ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516]: loading 141 CA certificates from Mozilla bundle. Update date: "Tue Aug 22 03:12:04 2023 GMT", SHA256: "23c2469e2a568362a62eecf1b49ed90a15621e6fa30e29947ded3436422de9b9"
[2023-09-21 23:08:13.952] [34212,34214] [debug] 53ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:08:14.054] [34212,34214] [debug] 101ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:08:34.057] [34212,34214] [debug] 20003ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> reached the end of list of bootstrap nodes, waiting for 500ms before restart
[2023-09-21 23:08:34.557] [34212,34214] [debug] 500ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:08:34.605] [34212,34214] [debug] 47ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:08:54.606] [34212,34214] [debug] 20000ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> reached the end of list of bootstrap nodes, waiting for 500ms before restart
[2023-09-21 23:08:55.106] [34212,34214] [debug] 500ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:08:55.146] [34212,34214] [debug] 40ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:09:15.147] [34212,34214] [debug] 20001ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> reached the end of list of bootstrap nodes, waiting for 500ms before restart
[2023-09-21 23:09:15.648] [34212,34214] [debug] 500ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:09:15.768] [34212,34214] [debug] 120ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:09:35.769] [34212,34214] [debug] 20000ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> reached the end of list of bootstrap nodes, waiting for 500ms before restart
[2023-09-21 23:09:36.269] [34212,34214] [debug] 500ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:09:36.313] [34212,34214] [debug] 44ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:09:56.317] [34212,34214] [debug] 20003ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> reached the end of list of bootstrap nodes, waiting for 500ms before restart
[2023-09-21 23:09:56.817] [34212,34214] [debug] 500ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> attempt to establish MCBP connection
[2023-09-21 23:09:56.850] [34212,34214] [debug] 32ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> connecting to 18.224.61.170:11207, timeout=20000ms
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.952] [34212,34214] [debug] 17102ms, all nodes failed to bootstrap, triggering DNS-SRV refresh, ec=unambiguous_timeout (14), last endpoint="svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207"
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.952] [34212,34214] [warning] 0ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> unable to bootstrap in time
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.953] [34212,34214] [debug] 0ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> stop MCBP connection, reason=do_not_retry
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.953] [34212,34214] [debug] 0ms, Query DNS-SRV: address="cb.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com", service="_couchbases", nameserver="127.0.0.53:53"
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.953] [34212,34214] [debug] 0ms, PYCBC: create conn callback completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_couchbase.py", line 30, in <module>
[2023-09-21 23:10:13.956] [34212,34214] [debug] 2ms, [db5876-95a9-4e45-b130-b8be0b1a2cc516/4b242f-59b5-cd40-0ae3-e094269c2ca35a/tls/-] <svc-dqis-node-001.qx8kjhcigkz1-bsp.cloud.couchbase.com:11207> destroy MCBP connection
    cluster = Cluster('couchbases://{}'.format(endpoint), options)
  File "/home/minura/anaconda3/envs/couchbase/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 99, in __init__
[2023-09-21 23:10:14.031] [34212,34214] [debug] 75ms, DNS UDP returned 1 records
    self._connect()
  File "/home/minura/anaconda3/envs/couchbase/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchbase/logic/wrappers.py", line 98, in wrapped_fn
    raise e
  File "/home/minura/anaconda3/envs/couchbase/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchbase/logic/wrappers.py", line 82, in wrapped_fn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/minura/anaconda3/envs/couchbase/lib/python3.8/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 105, in _connect
    raise ErrorMapper.build_exception(ret)
couchbase.exceptions.UnAmbiguousTimeoutException: UnAmbiguousTimeoutException(<ec=14, category=couchbase.common, message=unambiguous_timeout (14), C Source=/home/ec2-user/workspace/python/sdk/python-packaging-pipeline/py-client/src/connection.cxx:199>)
[2023-09-21 23:10:14.061] [34212,34212] [debug] 29ms, PYCBC: exception_base_dealloc completed
[2023-09-21 23:10:14.061] [34212,34212] [debug] 0ms, dealloc transaction_config
[2023-09-21 23:10:14.076] [34212,34212] [debug] 15ms, dealloc transaction_query_options
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share the debug logs & the SDK version that you are using?
For debug logs, you can run the script by setting the environment variable `PYCBC_LOG_LEVEL` to debug.
More details on logging here: https://docs.couchbase.com/python-sdk/current/howtos/collecting-information-and-logging.html

Comment: Hey @nithishr, I am using version 4.1.8 of the SDK and I have added the DEBUG logs to the question.

Comment: SDK Doctor is useful for diagnosing SDK connectivity issues.

In an application, the WaitUntilReady() method will show the 'reasons' if it times-out.

From the repeated attempts to connect to 18.224.61.170:11207 in the DEBUG information, it appears that either the server is not listening at that address, or the client does not have connectivity to the server.   A common issue is not adding the client to the "Allowed IPs" in Capella (but I see you said you have that).  You can verify connectivity with curl https://<ip>:11207.

Comment: It should give an "empty response" error as it is not https.   If there is no connectivity it will either give a timeout (usually not in Allowed IPs) or a "Connection Refused" (usually server not running)